# Trigger Function when Button is pressed like a keydown trigger in python on rasperry pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using an rasperry pi with latest raspian jessie installed.

I want to react to an keydown event, then a function should be called and executed exactly once and a parameter should be incremented.

what I currently have is

```
# Import Libraries
from gpiozero import LED,Button
from signal import pause
from time import sleep 

# LED Declaration
LED1 = LED(21)
LED2 = LED(16)
LED3 = LED(20)

# Button declaration
button = Button(19)

LED1.off()
LED2.off()
LED3.off()

current = 0

# Function for setting Outputs
def output(current):
    print(current)
    if current == 0:
        LED1.off()
        LED2.off()
        LED3.off()
    if current == 1:
        LED1.on()
        LED2.off()
        LED3.off()
    if current == 2:
        LED1.off()
        LED2.on()
        LED3.off()
    if current == 3:
        LED1.on()
        LED2.on()
        LED3.off()
    if current == 4:
        LED1.off()
        LED2.off()
        LED3.on()
    if current == 5:
        LED1.on()
        LED2.off()
        LED3.on()
    if current == 6:
        LED1.off()
        LED2.on()
        LED3.on()
    if current == 7:
        LED1.on()
        LED2.on()
        LED3.on()

def increment(current):
    print(current)
    if current < 7:
        current += 1
        output(current)
        return
    if current == 7:
        current = 0
        output(current)
        return


# Check for pressed button
while True:
    if button.when_pressed True:
        increment(current)
```

How can i keep sure that my function is just called once and my current variable is incremented correctly and not being reset to 0 when function is triggered once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, you try to use `current` to keep track of the state of the incrementor. But the `current` within the `increment` is not the same as the `current` in the global (module) namespace. Easiest way to circumvent this is to declare `current` as `global` in the increment function, but I think it is best to create a class to keep this state

```
class MyLeds()

    def __init__(self, *leds, current=0):
        self._leds = leds
        self._current = current

    def increment():
        self._current = (self._current + 1) % (2 ** len(self._leds) - 1)
        self._output()

    def _output():
        for i, led in enumerate(leds):
            on = self._current & 2**i
            led.on() if on else led.off()
            # print('led %i is %s' % (i+1, on))
```

I made the code also more flexible for more leds using [bitwise](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) `&`.

The rest of your script would look like this, then:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from gpiozero
    from signal import pause
    from time import sleep 

    # LED Declaration
    led_ports = (21, 16, 20)
    leds = tuple(gpiozero.LED(led) for led in led_ports)

    for led in leds:
        led.off()
    my_leds = MyLeds(leds)
    # Button declaration
    button = gpiozero.Button(19)

    while True:
        if button.when_pressed:
            my_leds.increment()
```

Comment: I don't have a rpi with a gpio board so I could not test this. I seem to have forgotten a +1 in `increment` and I fixed the condition in the `while True`-loop

Answer (score 1):

You while loop will block the GUI from working. So try using the button's command option to call a function. Also, it is best practice to use a class to create the GUI. It helps avoid using global variables, etc.

```
from tkinter import *

class Counter:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.current = 0
        # Button declaration
        button = Button(master, text='+', command=self.increment)
        button.grid()

    def increment(self):
        self.current += 1
        print(self.current)

root = Tk()
app = Counter(root)
root.mainloop()
```